# SSRS 2008 to SSRS 2017 Migration - Subscription issues

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2017

We have migrated from SQL 2008/SSRS 2008 to SQL 2017/SSRS 2017. We still have one issue where I cannot see the subscriptions I created in 2008.  Below is the error I get.

I have my domain account setup as System Administrator/System User in Site Settings and I am in an AD group that has Browser, Content Manager, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder to all folders/objects.

[image: Error Message when viewing subscriptions]

I have googled & googled and all articles point to this being a SECURITY issue, but I cannot see what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was some how an subscription ownership issue. I changed the owner of all my subscriptions to my new domain\user & this solved this issue.

```
DECLARE @OldUserID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @NewUserID uniqueidentifier
SELECT @OldUserID = UserID FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = 'old_domain\username'
SELECT @NewUserID = UserID FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = 'new_domain\username'
UPDATE dbo.Subscriptions SET OwnerID = @NewUserID WHERE OwnerID = @OldUserID
```